# Compiling Twitter Bootstrap Less files - compiler errors after clone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I've just cloned bootstrap from the official github repository.
When trying to compile the less files using the official less app however, I get the following errors:

[image: errors in less files]

...in a number of files. I have in my index.html file:

```
<link href="../less/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script src="../js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

With both scripts in the correct locations. The directory tree is as follows

```
-- bootstrap
  -- js
  -- html
  -- less
  -- img
  -- docs
```

Is there something I am missing to deploy this correctly? I only want to do static html and javascript files for a quick prototype project.

Update: here is the problem i get on the command line trying to build via the make method. Using the latest less.js script from the official website.

[image]

Comment: Which [official](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage) less app ?

Comment: Sorry - meant to say unofficial less mac app. Should also have mentioned that this is not compiling via the js method either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this app just doesn't support all the features of the Less language.

Check the official [Node.js way](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage) for server-side compiling.

Related question on a different system (check the workarounds) : [SimpLESS won't compile initializr generated Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11683600/1478467)

Answer (score 3):

**my 3 cent**: Why do you want to compile single files? You should only compile the "bootstrap.less" file. Not the other ones alone. The "bootstrap.less" includes all `@import` dependency statements. The "mixins.less" and the "variables.less" for example include most essential informations.

You can't just compile "responsive-navbar.less" because the variable @navbarCollapseWidth is not known there.

BTW: Less.app is not really "official". I use CodeKit (also by Bryan D K Jones) and this tool is smart enough to do the following: I save the my "responsive-navbar.less", it checks out the other files where this file might be included in and then compiles the mother file.

Comment: I realize this is months old now, but here is the correct response: 
less.app doesn't allow you to compile a single file if there are other less files in the same directory (or included, I can't recall). When you add the single bootstrap.less file, it automatically adds all related files and tries to compile those as well. This could be why it errors out at compile time, not just lack of compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

open your variable less file and check if these variables are empty.

@navbarCollapseWidth
@warningBorder

it cannot find the .clearfix() function so you have to create it yourself.

Are you sure you copied all the files correct?

Comment: As far as I can see all of the files are there correctly - all I did was git clone the repo so I'm not sure how anything wouldn't be there?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap has its own Makefile. You need to run `make` from the command line in the directory where Twitter Bootstrap is on your machine.