# How can I compile LESS files that @import other LESS files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, compilation, less

I'm trying to compile Twitter Bootstrap's LESS files into a the CSS file(s) needed to run Bootstrap.  I've tried using [LESS](http://incident57.com/less/) and [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless), but both throw errors.  Based on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683600/simpless-wont-compile-initializr-generated-bootstrap), it seems like the problem lies with the way Bootstrap `@import`s multiple LESS files (specifically, in [bootstrap.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less)).

So, my question: is there a simple way, preferably GUI but alternatively command-line, to compile LESS files that `@import` other LESS files into local CSS files?

EDIT: found [this error report](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/issues/97) for SimpLESS, along with [a fix](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/issues/97#issuecomment-13540609).  So, one answer (and probably my preference) to my question is SimpLESS.  However, I'm still interested in hearing about other options, to better understand how to use LESS.

Comment: Can you show the errors and the code? 
Also, try this if you want a windows GUI http://winless.org/

Comment: on mac, CodeKit works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this out -- per the [fix](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS/issues/97#issuecomment-13540609) I mentioned in the edit to my question, [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless) works with Bootstrap and handles @import statements just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this :
     function called @import-once, Instead of @import

Comment: unless he is using LESS 1.4 ---> `@import-once is removed and is now default behavior for @import`.